# Linux permissions: How to make permissions changes permanent

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I have /sys/kernel/debug/ with no read/execute permissions for anyone except root.

I can change that with `sudo chmod +rx /sys/kernel/debug/` but the permissions are reset every time I boot the system. Is there a way to make these permission changes permanent?

Is there a good reason why I really should not do that?

Comment: The reason why you shouldn't do that is perhaps that you can get access for regular users via sudo.

Comment: @AnonymousLurker that's what I'm doing with chmod, but I don't want to have to do it at every boot.

Comment: place it in `/etc/rc.local` and it will perform this action automatically.

Comment: @jonnat Actually I meant you can use sudo to become root as regular user, thus getting access to that without having to change any permissions at all.

Comment: I'm not so sure you want to be changing those files but you might take a look at the `chattr` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in the `/sys` tree (and the `/proc` tree) are dynamically created by the kernel, kernel modules, device drivers and so forth and hence are not permanent across reboots.

Hence the only way to force certain permissions is by adding a local init script to reset them after each reboot.

If you are happy for all users to have read access, then I can't think of a reason you shouldn't do it.